# Generalization of Caesar Algorithm decryption for 0 to 25 shifts

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I've written a small **Caesar Algorithm** decrypter (to test myself ) which only works if the encrypter shifts all the characters once to the right of English alphabet and **That's the Problem** !! . Would appreciate any help on how to make it work with more than 1 shift . (tried few approaches but none worked! Quite frustrating indeed :( )

```
text =  input('ENTER CIPHER HERE:')
def decrypt(text):
 b = ''
 for i in range(len(text)): 
  s1 = chr(((ord(text[i]) - 1 -65 )+ 26)%26 + 65)
  i = (i + 1)
  b = b + s1
  if  len(b) == len(text):
      print(b)
decrypt(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in `translate` method of strings for such a simple substitution cypher.

First, we generate the alphabet (lowercase only):

```
In [1]: lc = ''.join(chr(j) for j in range(97, 123))                                                     
Out[1]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Then we define a function to roll it:

```
In [2]: def roll_left(s, n): 
   ...:     return s[n:] + s[:n] 
   ...:                                                                                                  

In [3]: roll_left(lc, 13)                                                                                
Out[3]: 'nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm'

In [4]: roll_left(lc, 5)                                                                                 
Out[4]: 'fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde'
```

We use the original alphabet and the rolled version to make a translation table.

```
In [5]: t5 = str.maketrans(lc, roll_left(lc, 5))
```

To "encrypt" we apply that table to a string.

```
In [6]: 'this is a test'.translate(t5)                                                                    
Out[6]: 'ymnx nx f yjxy'
```

To decrypt, make an inverse translation table:

```
In [7]: tinv5 = str.maketrans(roll_left(lc, 5), lc)

In [8]: 'ymnx nx f yjxy'.translate(tinv5)                                                                
Out[8]: 'this is a test'
```

Comment: When used with a for loop ,will work like magic! Thanks(sorry for late response;-))